# Can any of the cache_* be emptied safely?

Tags: database, caching

Sometimes when moving the database it can be too large. Can any of the "cache_" prefixed tables be emptied without causing problems?

Comment: I have not encountered any problems so far, by truncating these tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With one exception, yes. That exception is `cache_form`. That is not actually a cache table but contains temporary $form_state information of forms currently displayed on your site. Clearing that table would invalidate these forms and when a user then tries to submit that form, he will get an error message and has to fill out that form again.

Note that `drush sql-dump` and [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) automatically leave out the content of these and other tables when creating a database dump with these instead of mysqldump or phpmyadmin.

Comment: drush sql-dump actually includes the 'cache_form' table.

Comment: @remote: I didn't mean to imply otherwise (althought I didn't know that it explicitly keeps cache_form). Feel free to edit (or suggest an edit) if you think my answer is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

There's a "false friend" in that list.
cache_form is not a cache table, and emptying it will invalidate all forms active on the site at that moment.

I also don't see a reason why you would use phpmyadmin for this.
It is clunky and error prone. "drush cc all" is your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the cache tables is keeping computed values. When a module calls [cache_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_get/7), and it gets back an empty value, then it just executes the code to obtain back the cached values.
All the modules I know automatically execute the code to get the value they were expecting in the cache, if the cache is empty; emptying the cache doesn't cause any problem to the modules using it.

Answer (score 3):

I have done it many times and haven't find any problem by doing it.

Important notice - try to clear **all** cache tables at once. This will prevent Drupal from using invalid cache data.

Comment: I have very important data in these tables, are you 120% sure? ;)

Comment: Yes, But for your very important data please take backup first. :)

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari If you have important data then it should really be stored somewhere else as well as the cache tables...

Comment: @j2r, Me too, I have done it several times. No problem. +1

Comment: @Chapabu I mean the site is important, I did not store any important data myself