# moving of a database [drupal-commons 6x25]: Which tables can be emptied safely?

Tags: database

I am running Drupal Commons 6.x25  (released February 2012); I have installed it yesterday locally on a lamp, on OpenSuse 12.1. Now I want to move it to the web server, but I have noticed that the fresh database—without any special module, beside the ones that are shipped with commons—is extremely large (16 Mbit).

Sometimes, the moving of a database can be too hard since the database is a way too large. Which Drupal tables are safe to manually clear using PhpMyAdmin?

What about all the "cache_" prefixed tables be emptied without causing problems?

**Background:** well - sometimes i have some troubles in meging the 16 db at once... but i continue to try to move a drupal-commons in a single step without any emptiying. BTW to **which extend we can lower the db-size of 16 mb - 10 or 5 mb probably.**

Comment: For what's it worth, 16MB is everything but extremely large :) Drupal Commons already consists of a large of list of modules, each one of them installs tables and data.

Comment: thx again Bedir - well - sometimes i have some troubles in meging the 16 db at once... but i continue to try to move a drupal-commons in a single step without any emptiying. BTW to which extend we can lower the **db-size of 16 mb - 10 or 5 mb probably.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to empty all "cache" prefixed tables, "watchdog" table and session table.

Comment: Careful when emptying cache_form, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/can-any-of-the-cache-be-emptied-safely. Shouldn't be a problem when moving to the webserver, though.

Comment: which ammount of Megabites do you have - when you empty all the unnecccary  tables!?