# Is safe to EMPTY all cache tables directly from database?

Tags: 7, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can any of the cache_* be emptied safely?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/can-any-of-the-cache-be-emptied-safely)

I have following cache table, is safe to EMPTY them form phpMyAdmin?

```
cache
cache_block
cache_bootstrap
cache_field
cache_filter
cache_form
cache_gravatar
cache_image
cache_mailchimp_user
cache_menu
cache_metatag
cache_page
cache_path
cache_token
cache_update
cache_views
cache_views_data
```